# Dynamics CRM forms: jScript for a dummy

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Breaking my head against more compex problems, I try to get back to basics.
I want to have a jScript in a form, that upon user change in control Sub-Fund, will pop up a message showing the new value of that control.
Here is my code -- which returns an error, of course 8-(((

```
function TestForDummy()
{
   var noind = crmForm.all.new_subfundid.DataValue;
   alert(noind);
}
```

Whenever I update Sub-Fund, it gives me an error
Field:new_subfundid, Event:onchange, Error:Object expected
What'wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
function TestForDummy() 
{ 
    var lookupValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_subfundid").getValue();   
    var noind = lookupValue[0].id;
    alert(noind); 
}
```

Comment: It's strange...I removed every other event from the form, and updated the web resource to your code, and I still have the same "object expected" error. Even with only 1 line of code `alert("hello");` it is the same.

Comment: Oooops...al my fault (of course). The name of the function was not properly spelled in the control properties form. Thanks, @dub. I'll now (hopefully) be able to attack the more complex lookup question.